# python program to print sequence of 7 numbers startting with user entered number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a program that asks the user to enter a number, n, which is -6

The numbers needed to be printed using a field width of 2 and need to be right justified. Fields must be seperated by a single space, with no space after the final field.

so far this is what i have got to this:

```
n = int(input("Enter the start number: "))
if n>-6 and n<93:
   for i in range(n, n+7):
      print("{:>2}".format(i), end="  ")
```

But I still seem to be getting spacing issues, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hello, it looks like a homework question, so you need to figure out the complete answer by yourself.
I can hint you to create a list of numbers and use `str.join`
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?str.join#str.join

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input("Enter the start number: "))
if n>-6 and n<93:
   for i in range(n, n+7):
       if i < n + 6:
           print("{:>2}".format(i), end="  ")
       else:
           print("{:>2}".format(i))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```py
n = int(input("Enter the start number: "))
width = int(input('Enter width : '))
if n>-6 and n<93:
   for i,val in enumerate(range(n,n+width)):
       if i==(width-1):
           print("{}".format(val))
       else:
            print("{}".format(val), 
            end="  ")
```

**Output**

```
Enter the start number: 5
Enter width : 5
5  6  7  8  9
```